# SharePoint 2007: How to cross-site lookup value?

Tags: sharepoint, content-type, lookup, site-column

I'm working in application build in SharePoint 2007, my question is can we do lookup value of Site Column across Site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only possible with third party :

http://www.boostsolutions.com/Cross-SiteLookup.html

Answer (score 1):

If your lookup list is at Site collection and the column is @sub sites of the site collection, then you can try by creating Site Columns as Look up type.

Answer (score 0):

Create your source list in the top-level site. In the same site create a lookup column looking up valies from that list, now you can use this column throughout the site collection.